# Where are all these columns coming from on the Entries in happy-lagger.test project?

Tags: craft3, control-panel

[image: Screenshot of the Craft Control Panel, Entries section]

I just started looking around the example project happy-lager, and I realised that on the Entries there's a bunch of columns displayed that I don't see on my company project (URI, Service Icon and some others in different Entries, such as background colour or image thumbnails). I didn't know this was possible, but it's great. How are those set?

FYI: Our project was updated from Craft 2, I don't know if this might be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every entry type (or even on the "All entries") you can specify the columns visible in the Panel. Click on the cog at the bottom of the light-grey sidebar. You'll have access to all entry' fields!

The magic of Craft ;)